# SimpleXMLElement having values stripped out on __soapCall

Tags: php, xml, soap, response

```
$domDocument = Hydrate($order);

$client = new SoapClient('http://10.1.208.120/api/webservice.asmx?WSDL', array('trace' => 1));

$xml = simplexml_load_string($domDocument->saveHTML());

$result = $client->SendOrder($xml);
```

Upon debug, $xml ends up having all my values correctly assigned where they should be.  Most notably, the DateTime values that I set in the Hydrate() method:

```
<ns1:OrderDate>2014-08-06T19:37:53+00:00</ns1:OrderDate>
```

When I SendOrder(), I get:

> Server was unable to read request. --> There is an error in XML
>   document (2, 515). --> String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.

And my DateTime values end up being blank:

```
<ns1:OrderDate/>
```

I'm beyond frustrated with this.  Does anyone know what's going on?

Edit:

The problem was that I was not using namespaces when generating the DomDocument. I just prepended ns1: to all elements and used a SoapVar and __SoapCall.

```
$this->setSoapClient(new SoapClient( $this->getURL() .'?WSDL', array('trace' => 1)));
$this->setSoapRequest(Mage::getModel('apiorder/domdocbuilder')->Hydrate($this->getOrder())->saveHTML());
$this->setSoapBody(new SoapVar($this->getSoapRequest(), XSD_ANYXML));

try
{
    $this->setSoapResult($this->getSoapClient()->__SoapCall('SendOrder', array($this->getSoapBody())));
}
catch(SoapFault $e)
{
    $this->setSoapFault($e);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that I was not using namespaces when generating the DomDocument.  I just prepended ns1: to all elements and used a SoapVar and __SoapCall.

```
$this->setSoapClient(new SoapClient( $this->getURL() .'?WSDL', array('trace' => 1)));
$this->setSoapRequest(Mage::getModel('apiorder/domdocbuilder')->Hydrate($this->getOrder())->saveHTML());
$this->setSoapBody(new SoapVar($this->getSoapRequest(), XSD_ANYXML));

try
{
    $this->setSoapResult($this->getSoapClient()->__SoapCall('SendOrder', array($this->getSoapBody())));
}
catch(SoapFault $e)
{
    $this->setSoapFault($e);
}
```